# Documentation for options to lucidabr package

Tags: fonts, documentation, lucida

In postings related to the `lucidabr` package (like [here](https://tug.org/pipermail/lucida/2009-December/000306.html)) one sometimes sees options like `expert`, `nofontinfo`, `lucidascale`, and so on.  I tried to find documentation for them, but didn't succeed so far.  Where can I find a list of all options together with their meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The “manual” that comes from `lucidabr.sty` is indeed not very detailed.

Reading the package code, we identify the options

```
expert noexpert
nolucidascale lucidascale lucidasmallscale
mathitalic1 mathitalic2 mathitalic3
slantedgreek uprightgreek vargreek
noamssymbols
OT1 T1 LY1
seriftt
fax casual calligraphic handwriting
altbullet
errorshow warningshow nofontinfo
```

and the default options are

```
noexpert,lucidascale,slantedgreek,mathitalic1,errorshow
```

Let's examine the various groups.

### `expert` `noexpert`

The former relies on the full set of Lucida Bright fonts available and defines some more math fonts, namely `mathupright` for using different upright letters in math, instead of the standard text ones. It also assigns more fonts to the `bold` math version.

### `nolucidascale` `lucidascale` `lucidasmallscale`

With the `nolucidascale` option the fonts are simply scaled at the stated font size; with `lucidascale` the scaling is adjusted to emulate “optical” scaling; for instance at 10pt the font will be scaled at 95% of what would be the normal size, but at 11pt the scaling will be 94%, down to 89% for fonts above 22.5pt. With `lucidasmallscale` the percentages are lower.

### `mathitalic1` `mathitalic2` `mathitalic3`

The first option uses `it` shape for math letters; the second one uses `itx` so some letters will be slightly different. With `mathitalic3`, math letters will be upright.

### `slantedgreek` `uprightgreek` `vargreek`

The first two are self-explaining: uppercase Greek letters in math will be either slanted or upright. Note that `uprightgreek` needs `expert`. The `vargreek` option defines `\up<letter>` and `\var<Letter>` for Greek letters.

### `noamssymbols`

This option doesn't load the Lucida version of the symbols provided by `amssymb`.

### `OT1` `T1` `LY1`

These options choose the requested encoding for the `operators` math font.

### `seriftt`

This option sets a different font for typewriter type than the default.

### `fax` `casual` `calligraphic` `handwriting`

These options are for the text fonts. The first two choose a different family for the text fonts, the last two act on the italic fonts.

### `altbullet`

This uses the Computer Modern bullet, rather than the Lucida version

### `errorshow` `warningshow` `nofontinfo`

These are for debugging font usage.

Answer (score 3):

They are deducible, I wouldn't exactly say documented, from the package documentation lucidabr.pdf available from

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/psnfssx/lucidabr

which says

> The new Expert set for bold math

At least in its original distributions the fonts were available in two sets, a basic set and at extra cost an "expert" set that included fonts for bold math.

So the `expert` option configures latex `\boldmath` to use the optional fonts.

The `lucidascale` option is

> Set up the variant text and math sizes which Y&Y suggest for Lucida. The figures for these two options actually come from Frank Mittelbach (oh great one). The default is to scale, but two options allow you to revert to normal behaviour, or get even smaller

Comment: The quoted text must have been written by Sebastian, not me:-)

Answer (score 2):

You have the alternative of using the OpenType versions of the fonts in `unicode-math`.

It’s possible to download additional fonts similar to `expert`, including `handwriting` and `calligraphy`, from [Lucida Fonts](https://lucidafonts.com/).

You can get a different upright alphabet from the text letters by loading it with `\setmathfont[range=up]{...}`.  Then, `\symup` will get you upright math letters and `\mathrm` the default text font.  I sometimes use this to load Upright Italic fonts for upright math, or Hermann Zapf’s Euler as an upright companion for Palatino/Asana/Pagella.

The options like `lucidascale` are replaced by the `Scale=` font option.  I normally set `Scale=Lowercase` as the default and load the main font at `Scale=1.0`, so it appears at its natural size and all fonts are scaled to the same x-height.

The `mathitalic1` and `mathitalic2` options would be replaced by `\setmathfont[range=it]{...}` and using `\symit`.  As with `\mathrm`, `\mathit` gibes you the default text font.

The `\mathitalic3` option is equivalent to `\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}`.  The `slantedgreek` option is equivalent to `\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}`.

The `\seriftt` option is equivalent to loading a different font with `\setmonofont`.

The `altbullet` option would be something like `\setmathfont[range=\bullet]{Latin Modern Math}`.

There are no equivalents to selecting an 8-bit font encoding: you will be using Unicode.  There is also no equivalent for `noamssymbols`, because the limit on the number of math alphabets is gone.

Unfortunately, selecting `\setmathfont` with a `range=` is incompatible with selecting a `version=`, as of Unicode-Math 0.8q, and you need `\setmathfont[version=bold]{LucidaBrightMathOT-Demi.otf}` to use `\boldmath` or `\boldsymbol`.